# RSpec How to add meta data for helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to add custom tag for my rspec test. Example:

```
it 'should do something', transactional: false do
end
```

The custom tag is **transactional: false**.

And then in my database_cleaner_helper.rb, I can write something like below.

```
before(:suite) do
    if (it.tags[:transactional] == true) 
    else
    end
end
```

Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my own solution as follows. Since I'm using database cleaner to truncate the database before running any test, and rspec metadata is only applicable for each test; I have to use environment variables to control this. The result look like below.

```
database_cleaner = ENV['DATABASE_CLEANER']

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do 
      if database_cleaner.nil? || database_cleaner == 'true'
          DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
          Rails.application.load_seed
      end
  end

  # More code here
end
```

Also just to point out this, you can't do `config.before(:suite, transactional: true)`. It's not available as of `rspec-rails 3.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax would be like

```
before(:suite, transactional: true) do
  # do something
end
```

See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/filters

Comment: What is the difference between :suite and :example

Comment: This answer is wrong. It will be ignored. It will give this error: WARNING: `:suite` hooks do not support metadata since they apply to the suite as a whole rather than any individual example or example group that has metadata. The metadata you have provided will be ignored.

Comment: @TrongBang `before(:suite)` will be applied before the whole test suite you are running.
Then I guess you just have to change the hook to
`before(:each, transactional: true)` to do something before each example (`ìt ...`) that has the transactional tag set to true.

Comment: Actually I have some database cleanup in before(:suite). Hence, running before(:each) doesn't help in this case